# How to programmatically clear search textfield inside a Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

In my Page there are multiple jquery datatbles.I want to programmatically reset search textfield inside one of the Jquery Datatable.

```
  var dtTaskEmployee= $('#tblEmployee').DataTable({});
  $('#modalEmployeeDetails').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
     $('input[type=search]').val('');
     dtTaskEmployee.search('').draw();
  })
```

But this one cleares all the search fields inside all the datatble. I want to clear the search input field inside dtTaskEmployee. Can anyone help on this

Comment: Assuming `dtTaskEmployee` is a jQuery object: `dtTaskEmployee.find('input[type=search]').val('');` ?

Comment: `$('input[type=search]').val('')` -> `$('#tblEmployee input[type=search]').val('')`

Comment: @connexo dtTaskEmployee is jquery datatable object.I have updated the question.Above solution is not working

Comment: @freedomn-m Close, but it's `$('#tblEmployee_filter input[type=search]').val('');`

Comment: @user12031119 wouldn't `#tblEmployee_filter` be *inside* `#tblEmployee`?  (genuinely not checked, so perhaps not if #tblEmployee is a `table`) And OP states "clear field inside dtTaskEmployee" where dtTaskEmployee is the datatable for #tblEmployee?   So either would work, but adding "_filter" makes assumptions on how datatables internally works and may break with a new release.

Comment: @freedomn-m DataTables does do a lot of DOM manipulation and changes the ID of the table to `#tblEmployee_wrapper`.  It also creates a separate div with the search field and suffixes it with `_filter` to `#tblEmployee_filter`.  While it's true future releases of DataTables could break the code, it's highly unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input[type=search]').val('');` will clear all search fields so you want to limit this to `#tblEmployee` only.

```
var dtTaskEmployee= $('#tblEmployee').DataTable({});
$('#modalEmployeeDetails').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#tblEmployee_filter input[type=search]').val('');
   dtTaskEmployee.search('').draw();
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!..Its's working perfectly